# Is there any way to stop the listening from Socket.io?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I try to stop listening in socket.io.
For example, in my case, I get the data from a socket like this.

```
Socket.on('event', function(data) {}}
```

How can I stop listening in socket.io?
Thanks

Comment: I was confronted with a similar problem just like this, and this article was helpful for me.

Comment: I faced this issue and this article was helpful for me
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### To close the connection:

`socket.close()` or `socket.disconnect()`

> Returns Socket
>
> Disconnects the socket manually.

### To stop listening to some specific listener

`socket.off('event', function(){})`

> Unbind the specified event handler (opposite of .on()).
>
> If you decide to use this method, be careful! socket.off() does not stop the this client-side socket from receiving any server-sent messages, it just prevents the specified event handler from firing.

Actually, a socket instance inherits every method from `Emitter` class (https://github.com/component/emitter), so you can use `.hasListeners()`, `.once()` and already said `.off()` (to remove an specific event listener).

Here you find a nice doc about these and other Socket.io methods: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/web-sockets/socket-client/io-socket-on

Answer (score 6):

**To unsubscribe all listeners of an event**

```
socket.off('event-name');
```

**To unsubscribe a certain listener**

```
socket.off('event-name', listener);
```

Or You can use following things also,

```
socket.removeListener(eventName, listener)
socket.removeAllListeners([eventName])
```

Ref: https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-removeListener-eventName-listener

Comment: Nice. I didn't remember `removeAllListeners`. Cool

Answer (score 2):

The 'off' function can also be used.

1. socket.off('news'); // stops listening to the "news" event
2. socket.off('news', myFunction); // useful if you have multiple
   listeners for the same event socket.off(); // stops listening to all events

Comment: `socket.off() stops listening to all events` +1